# Is $ \pi $ definable in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,×, <,\exp) $?

Tags: real-analysis, model-theory, first-order-logic

Is there a first-order formula $\phi(x) $ with exactly one free variable $ x $ in the language of ordered fields together with the unary function symbol $ \exp $ such that in the standard interpretation of this language in $\Bbb R $ (where $ \exp $ is interpreted as the exponential function $ x \mapsto e^x $), $\phi (x) $ holds iff $ x=\pi $?

EDIT: As Levon pointed out, a negative answer to this problem would imply that $π$ and $e$ (and $e^e$, $(2e)^{3e^2}$, and so on) are algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q$, which is an unsolved problem. So, if you think that a definition of $\pi$ is impossible, I would be pleased if you could show something like, that it is possible to reduce $\phi$ to a formula which contains no terms involving bound variables inside exponential functions, which would reduce the problem more or less to a question on algebraical independece.
However because there are such intricate connections between exponential and trigonometric functions, I don't think that $\pi$ should be undefinable.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: One can define $2x=\pi$ as the least positive real such that $\sin x=0$. Given the intimate relation with $\exp$ and the trigonometric functions, can you work something out?

Comment: But complex numbers are needed for that..

Comment: @Berci Yes, I know.

Comment: A negative answer would imply $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Aren't they? $\,$

Comment: Since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$, we could express $\pi$ as a square of the value of this integral. I think we can express this in first order language.

Comment: @Berci As far as I know, it is unknown whether they are algebraically independent.

Comment: I was sure they are.

Comment: @Berci: It's not even known whether or not $e+\pi$ is irrational. Schanuel's conjecture would imply that, and quite a few other things, but it's wide open as far as I know.

Comment: [Carl's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415966/is-pi-definable-in-bbb-r-0-1-exp/416022?noredirect=1#comment889645_416022) implies that Peter's approach can't work. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Are you sure? It's clear that we can't define the entire zero set of $\sin$ (or the function itself), but is it clear that we can't define even a single zero?

Comment: I suppose I'm not. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Bummer?

Comment: Partial answer.  Leave out exp, answer is "no".

There are models of $(\Bbb R,0,1,+, \times, \lt)$ (that is, real-closed fields) that do not contain $\pi$.  An easily described one is the set of all algebraic real numbers.

Comment: Actually my comment was meant in such a way that i would be satisfied if one could prove that for every definition $\phi$ of $\pi$ in $\Bbb R_{exp}$ there is a defintion $\psi$ of $n$ with some kind of "exponential function elimination" (e. g. containing no term of the form $\forall a e^a =...$, etc.).

Comment: Wilkie's full result is that $\mathbb{R}_{\exp}$ is o-minimal and \emph{model complete}: that is, every definable set is defined by an existential formula of the language. You can't go further and eliminate all quantifiers. 

So a definable number in $\mathbb{R}_{\exp}$ is one co-ordinate of a solution to a set of simultaneous equations (& inequalities) with integer coefficients. You can use the algebraic properties of $\exp$ to simplify the terms in the equation at the cost of adding extra bound variables. But there's no way in general to ensure their exponentials don't appear---far from it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Todd Trimble provided [the answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136642/37059) on MO:

Assuming [Shanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), [this treatise](http://www.fedoa.unina.it/2845/1/Terzo_Scienze_Matematiche.pdf) about exponential rings proves that (see Theorem 2.5.1) the exponential ring generated by $\pi$ looks just as the exponential ring generated by nearly every other real number, which implies that there is **no defining relation** of $\pi$ over $\Bbb R_{\exp}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$

$$
\phi(x) := (\forall_y \psi(y) \implies y^2 = x)
$$

Where 
$$
\psi(y) := \forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_N \forall_{n > N} \forall_x s(n, x) \implies |x - y| < \epsilon
$$
The formula $\psi(y)$ says that $y$ is a limit of $x_n$ such that $s(n, x_n)$ holds. Now, $s(n, x)$ says that $\int_{-n}^n e^{-t^2} = x$:

$$
s(k, x) = \forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_N \forall_{n > N} \forall_y p(n, k, y) \implies |x - y| < \epsilon
$$

Now $p(n, k, y)$ says that $y$ is a value of k-th Riemann sum of integral $\int_{-n}^n e^{-t^2}$. I'll leave the details.

Comment: How do you define the Riemann sum in this structure (which cannot even define or quantify over $\mathbb{N}$)?

Comment: @Carl : $\:$ How do you know that this structure cannot define $\mathbb{N}$? $\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky Demer: Alex Wilkie proved in 1999 that the structure $\mathbb{R}_{\text{exp}}$ is o-minimal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory

Comment: (Note: I have upvoted this, not because I agree but because -3 seemed harsh for a well-meant (and flawed) attempt.)

Comment: One would then similarly use $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx/(1+x^2)$ to define $\pi$ without using $\exp$ at all, which is impossible.