# First order definition of $\pi$

Tags: first-order-logic, pi

$e$ has a very short first-order definition. It's the only constant that makes this true:
$$\forall x,e^x\ge x+1$$
What about $\pi$? What's the shortest first-order definition we could give *it*?

I'm including things like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, (real) exponentiation, roots, inequalities, etc. $\forall$ and $\exists$ range over $\Bbb R$. If you want to use differentiation or limits, expand it into its $\epsilon-\delta$ form.

Comment: what is the definition of "first-order" here?

Comment: @ZelosMalum Not talking about sets. Although I suppose a second-order definition is fine if it's short enough.

Comment: $C/d$ for a circle :P

Comment: @ZelosMalum That's longer than it looks. You have to define a circle, define the _length of a curve_… all in a first-order definition.

Comment: You need to keep to a certain alphabet. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I know, I was being humerous hence the ":P" was included

Comment: @columbus8myhw Real exponentiation is not so trivial as well. Its definition involves limits of rational exponentiations, which involve $n$-th roots...

Comment: @Crostul That's why I had to explicitly state that I was allowing it.

Comment: Maybe you could use $\sum n^{-2}=\pi^2/6$.

Comment: @Lucian That would be something like $\forall a\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}(a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}\land a_0=0)\implies \pi=\sup_n\{2^{n+1}\sqrt{2-a_n}\}$. Technically, we'd have to expand $\sup$ into its parts… It's pretty complicated, and I'm not sure the $\forall a\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ part is allowed.

Comment: @Lucian I only allowed real exponentiation.

Comment: If you extend $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and real operations to complex ones, you can define $\pi$ as the least real number (complex number with no imaginary part) for which we have $\exp(i\pi)+1=0$. I think you also need to add conjugation operator or real/imaginary part operator because of the terms "real number" and "least" above.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415966/is-pi-definable-in-bbb-r-0-1-%C3%97-exp) could be related.

Comment: You must avoid the "things like" and "etc" in the problem statement. Otherwise we may include "things like" $f(x)=\pi$.

Comment: @Watson: More than being related, I think it answers the question in the negative as well as could be hoped for! The [mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136627/is-%cf%80-definable-in-bbb-r-0-1-%c3%97-exp/136642#136642) has a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best definition of the sort you require I can think of is by Stirling's factorial approximation:

$$\forall n \geq 1, \pi \leq \frac{e^{2n}(n!)^2}{2 n^{2n+1}}$$

I don't think there is any such definition that doesn't use $e$ though.

Added an illustration (the convergence is very slow, but it doesn't matter for the OP's question):

[image]

Comment: "I don't think there is..." There is. Just use the fact that $\pi =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n}n!^4}{n(2n)!^2}$.

Comment: @PoderRac That could be posted as its own answer.

Comment: I don't think using factorials is very sporting, since all their standard definitions involve an iterative process or a sum or an integral. If we are allowing factorials (and are over the reals, as assumed), then there's a much simpler formula: $\pi=(-0.5)!^2$

Answer (score 3):

$ \pi < 4$ and for every integer $n \ge 3$ there is a complex $n$-th root of unity $\omega_n$ such that $$n |\omega_n -1| < 2\pi < (n+1) |\omega_n -1|$$

Comment: Quoting the OP: "I'm including things like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, (real) exponentiation, roots, inequalities, etc. $\forall$ and $\exists$ range over $\Bbb R$". Your definition uses complex numbers.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli : no, I'm using only addition, multiplication  of real numbers $<$ and $\exists$, as complex root unity and $|.|^2$ requires only those

Comment: Good point. Fine by me.

Comment: You're quantifying over integers $n$, so you're implicitly using the predicate "is an integer"; that predicate might or might not be included in the OP's "things like" and "etc."

Comment: @user1952009, I'm curious, is your definition a smart way to define the circumference in terms of inscribed and circumscribed regular polygons, like ancients did?

Comment: @Yuriy : yes I thought to  the circumference of the inscribed $n$ regular polygon which leads to $n |1-\omega_n| = 2n \sin(\pi / n)< 2 \pi$, but not to the circumscribed polygon whose circumference should be $2n \tan(\pi / n) =  \frac{\textstyle 2n |1-\omega_n|}{\textstyle \omega_{2n}+\overline{\omega_{2n}}}$  with $\omega_n = e^{2 i \pi /n}$